# Apply conditional formatting on the columns of a pivot table, where the values are shown as a percentage

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, pivot-table

My data includes the revenue from different products(around 6-7 products) marketed by different salespersons(around 5). I have a pivot table with the product labels in the row and sum of revenue of each product in the values. I want to express the revenue as a percentage of the grand total(total sales), and apply conditional formatting to highlight the percentage of revenue of each product, to the total revenue. I want to use a three colour scale or icon set of three symbols to show the performance- good, okay, bad. I have attached an image which should provide a rough idea of what the pivot table looks like
[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEe5M.png)
The conditional formatting rules I have are shown in the image below
[Conditional formatting rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfHA2.png)

What I wanted was,45% should get a green icon, and 39% should get a yellow icon, and the remaining 2 values should get a red icon. How can I achieve this? I tried entering the percentages as 0.40 and 0.20 but that did not work. Any suggestions involving three colour scale are also welcome.
P.S. If I can get this to work, I intend to add the salesperson in the column, and do a similar conditional formatting again, for each column.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using conditional formatting "Percent" as shown in your screenshot means Excel will check values and see how far they are between the lowest and highest values in the data.
So if your data includes zero and 50, for example, then a value of 20 would be at 40 percent between the extremes.
If your data goes from 10 to 30, then 20 would be at 50%

Rather than Percent, you just want to use **Number**, then stick to your instinct of converting to 0.4 and 0.2 because, as you have realised, 40% is really just 0.4.

(The Percentile option is different again depends on how many values there are and how they are distributed, so is even further from what you want)